# Beaglebone black and RaspberryPi fastest time response

Tags: raspberry-pi, signal-processing, beagleboneblack

Does anybody know what the fastest processing times are for the beaglebome black and the RaspberryPi. By processing time, i refer to reading a really fast input signal across any two of their input pins.

Context:
I am building a small particle detector and the pmt output, which i will connect directly to the beaglebone black or a RasberryPi for processing, is 3.3V and ~40ns wide. I am concerned whether these signals will be too fast for these micro-computers to even detect it. And i cant seem to find that info anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beaglebone black has programmable realtime units (PRU) that run at 200 MHz (5ns per instruction).  With these you will be able to reliably detect and count pulses >=15ns wide that are at least 30ns or so apart.

See this presentation. It's really quite awesome: http://beagleboard.org/pru

Raspberry Pi doesn't have anything similar with real time/reliability guarantees.  I don't know whether or not there's a clever way you could get it to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt.